# Why don't new operator definitions persist in the Perl 6 REPL?

Tags: operators, user-defined-functions, read-eval-print-loop, raku

I was having issues experimenting with defining operators on the Perl 6 REPL, and noticed that they do work, but only when used on the same line as they are defined. Why is this the case?

```
> sub postfix:<!>(Int $x where { $x >= 0 }) { [*] 1..$x }; 6!;
720
> 6!;
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Negation metaoperator not followed by valid infix
------> 6!⏏;
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
```

Comment: Also if you use -M to pull in a module it only works on the first line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug.

See bug reports [Perl6 REPL forgets the definition of ...](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131530) and [REPL issue defining new operator...](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131900) for more details.