# How does the scope effect EVAL of an infix:<> sub?

Tags: scope, raku, subroutine, infix-notation

This code works as expected:

```
sub infix:<mean>(*@a) {
    @a.sum / @a.elems
}
sub Mean (*@a) {
    @a.sum  / @a.elems
}

say EVAL 'Mean 2, 6, 4';     # Output: 4
say EVAL '2 mean 6 mean 4';  # Output: 4
```

It works as expected when line 7 is in its own scope:

```
{say EVAL 'Mean 2, 6, 4';}   # Output: 4
```

But when line 8 is in its own scope:

```
{say EVAL '2 mean 6 mean 4';} 

===SORRY!=== Error while compiling .../EVAL_1
Two terms in a row
at .../EVAL_1:1
------> 2⏏ mean 6 mean 4
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
```

Why are the two subs treated differently?

Comment: When I run the code you show in a 2022.02 Rakudo it all works. My two hypotheses are 1: you're using the REPL, which is buggy, (cf [Why don't new operator definitions persist in the Raku REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896386/why-dont-new-operator-definitions-persist-in-the-perl-6-repl/51903658#51903658)) or 2: some related or different bug is in recent Rakudos (which I currently think unlikely but still). I don't have time right now to investigate further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue, also affecting the REPL.

Problem is that doing a string `EVAL` will "see" the surrounding scope with all of its additions, so:

```
say EVAL 'infix:<mean>(infix:<mean>(2, 6), 4)';
```

**will** produce 4, because the sub `&infix:<mean>(*@a)` **is** known.

But the grammar changes to allow it to work as an infix, are currently *not* seen inside the `EVAL`.  And that's why you see the compile time error.

I have good hopes we will be able to fix this with the new Raku grammar, based on RakuAST.

Comment: FYI [the code in the Q currently works in glot.io (which reports it's using Rakudo 2202.02)](https://glot.io/snippets/gmgc4pbswa).

Comment: Intriguing!   Guess someone needs to do a bisect then.

Comment: My summary of [a gist summarizing some runs of bisectable](https://gist.github.com/raiph/3bb4a5a8a532149af8cd2e27d9c4d72f) is that it broke for most of 2017, and then broke again early this year, and the info bisectable provided was only definitive about what fixed it early in 2018 (a [commit by Zoffix](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/e509c1a9fdd5fb33657d25d0b4529d99e42cab33)).